# How to "flatten" a table in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I want to make a query over the table `MyTable` that uses its values in order to generate columns.

In the column `DATA_TYPE` it is guaranteed that there are only `1`, `2` and `3` as possible values.

`MyTable`:

```
CATEGORY     DATA_TYPE   DATA_CONTENT   OTHER_CONTENT
----------   ---------   ------------   -------------
CATEGORY A   1           CONTENT 1      OTHER 1    
CATEGORY A   2           CONTENT 2      OTHER 2    
CATEGORY A   3           CONTENT 3      OTHER 3    
CATEGORY B   1           CONTENT 1      OTHER 1    
CATEGORY B   2           CONTENT 2      OTHER 2    
CATEGORY B   3           CONTENT 3      OTHER 3    
CATEGORY C   1           CONTENT 1      OTHER 1    
CATEGORY C   2           CONTENT 2      OTHER 2    
CATEGORY C   3           CONTENT 3      OTHER 3
```

This is the desired result:

```
CATEGORY     DATA_TYPE_1   DATA_TYPE_2   DATA_TYPE_3   OTHER_1   OTHER_2   OTHER_3   
----------   -----------   -----------   -----------   -------   -------   -------   
CATEGORY A   CONTENT 1     CONTENT 2     CONTENT 3     OTHER 1   OTHER 2   OTHER 3   
CATEGORY B   CONTENT 1     CONTENT 2     CONTENT 3     OTHER 1   OTHER 2   OTHER 3   
CATEGORY C   CONTENT 1     CONTENT 2     CONTENT 3     OTHER 1   OTHER 2   OTHER 3
```

Comment: What you're after is called a `PIVOT` (or `UNPIVOT`), however I don't recommend doing this in SQL because the _display_ of data is a concern of your presentation layer (e.g. PHP), and not SQL (SQL is only concerned with getting _rows_ of data, it is not suitable for columnar manipulations)

Comment: What DBMS are you using (Sql Server, Oracle, etc..)? This will be some type of PIVOT() operation, but the syntax and support for those functions will vary by DBMS.

Comment: @dai While true when the number of columns would be variable, this is a fixed number of columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  category,
  MAX(CASE WHEN data_type = 1 THEN  data_content END)  AS data_type_1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN data_type = 2 THEN  data_content END)  AS data_type_2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN data_type = 3 THEN  data_content END)  AS data_type_3,
  MAX(CASE WHEN data_type = 1 THEN other_content END)  AS other_1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN data_type = 2 THEN other_content END)  AS other_2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN data_type = 3 THEN other_content END)  AS other_3
FROM
  myTable
GROUP BY
  category
```